# Do any other Overwatch heroes know Soldier:76's and Reaper's real identities?

Tags: overwatch

Soldier: 76 is Jack Morrison, former commander of Overwatch, and Reaper is Gabriel Reyes, former head of the Blackwatch arm of Overwatch.

After the explosion on Overwatch HQ in which both are presumed dead, it's unclear to me who knows who Soldier: 76 actually is and who Reaper actually is.  As an example, Mercy clearly knows that S:76 is Jack and Reaper is Gabriel -- so does Ana.  But Pharah's voice line with S:76 indicates that perhaps she isn't aware of who he really is, as indicated by:

> S76: Your mother would've been proud of you, y'know...
>
> Pharah: I guess you didn't know my mother very well...

Thus, are there any Overwatch heroes who are simply unaware who these two heroes are, canonically?   Is everyone on the team fully aware that S:76 is Jack, and Reaper is Gabe, or are some still clueless as to who they are?

Comment: "*I guess you didn't know my mother very well...*" doesn't mean anything, really. There are times when I say something similar to my own father (except I use "do" instead of "did").

Comment: @Nolonar Agreed, I don't believe that line represents Pharah not knowing who Soldier:76 is. I think she means it as "You don't know how my mother treats me/thinks of me."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line by Pharah, I don't think she's implying that S76 doesn't know Ana. I think she does know he's Jack and she's implying that, while he has a working relationship with Ana, he doesn't know how she is as a mother or the relationship between Pharah and Ana.

To answer your question, Mercy seems to be aware of Reaper's identity, as demonstrated in this voice clip:

Winston also has some interaction with S76 that suggests he knows but I can't find the quote online, I'll look it up and edit this post if I find it.

Also it seems Reaper and S76 are aware of each others identity.

Comment: Its probably worth transcribing the relevant quote from the video. I watched it and must have missed the relevant line...